# I'm trying to do a best fit algorithm in python in OS

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to get the output that is supposed to show but the blockSize is the same as memorySize (which is decreasing but I need my blockSize to stay as its initial one) Plus if there's any improvement of best fit that you can suggest, do tell!

```
def bestFit(blockSize,m,jobSize,n):
    allocation=[-1] * n
    memorySize=blockSize
    print(blockSize)
    for i in range(n):
        bestId = -1
        for j in range(m):
            if memorySize[j] >= jobSize[i]:
                if bestId == -1:
                    bestId = j
                    
                elif memorySize[bestId] > memorySize[j]:
                    bestId = j
                    
        if bestId != -1:
            allocation[i] = bestId
            memorySize[bestId] -= jobSize[i]
    print(blockSize)
    print("Job No. | Job Size. | Memory Size | Internal Fragmentation")
    
    for k in range(n):
        print("   ",k, "     ",jobSize[k],"         ",blockSize[allocation[k]],"            ",blockSize[allocation[k]]-jobSize[k])
        
blockSize = [100, 500, 200, 300, 600] 
processSize = [212, 417, 112, 426] 
  
bestFit(blockSize, len(blockSize) , processSize, len(processSize))
```

Comment: Would be nice to express your intent better, what is expected output and what is an actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [copy.copy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) to get a copy of your variable in line 3

```python
from copy import copy

def bestFit(blockSize,m,jobSize,n):
    allocation=[-1] * n
    memorySize=copy(blockSize)
...
```